# To make a compact list in r-markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

From [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543872/using-beginenumerate1-with-enumitem) I know that `enumitem` provides an option `nosep` which removes all spacing before and after the list as well as between the items, which works well in pure latex file `test.tex` as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Each $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is either an even face or contains exactly 2 faces in its interior;
\item the interiors of distinct $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are disjoint.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[47]

\end{document}
```

I try to realize this `nosep` functionality in the rmd file `test.rmd` to make a compact file and then I try:

````
---
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: pdflatex 
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum} 
  - \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
  - \setlist{nosep}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Each $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is either an even face or contains exactly 2 faces in its interior;
\item the interiors of distinct $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are disjoint.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[47]
````

The spacing between the items is fine with the output PDF of `test.rmd`, but **the spacing before and after the list keeps unchanged**, which is very different from the output PDF of `test.tex`! Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your latex code and the rmarkdown code is that rmarkdown will automatically load all kinds of unnecessary packages, amongst others the `parskip` package, which will add some vertical space between paragraphs. You can remove this vertical space like this

````
---
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: pdflatex 
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum} 
  - \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
  - \setlist{nosep}
  - \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Each $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is either an even face or contains exactly 2 faces in its interior;
\item the interiors of distinct $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are disjoint.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[47]
````

[image]

(you might want to combine it with something like `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}` so paragraphs will again be recognisable)

Comment: Wow, it works! Very impressive! @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz